# Missing or Invalid Url Parameter with Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am using the Twitter API's Search Tweets endpoint  (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) to search for tweets on a particular topic. My application is written in Java and uses Twitter4j. I follow the guidelines (i.e. no more than 180 calls per minute and no more than 500 characters per query) however I do have a test case that has 50 word exclusions (so the total character count is 397). My test program also runs 100 such searches in rapid succession though, like I said, I observe the rate limits strictly.

The odd behavior I'm seeing is that the test runs fine and gets results initially, but after an arbitrary period of time, I start getting the following error:

Message: Missing or invalid url parameter. 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Missing or invalid url parameter.
code - 195

The error message confuses me because I'm not trying to perform any of the update actions listed in the link provided. I'm just searching tweets. I'm also not sure what "missing or invalid url parameter" means. Is a query parameter missing from my request? The only required parameter is the query itself which I am definitely passing. The url is definitely correct unless Twitter4j is generating incorrect urls. So what does this message mean?

When I stop and restart the search (i.e. the max_id and since_id values get reset to -1, the searches start working again...for a while. As far as I know, nothing else about the search changes when it is restarted. Just those two ids.

Comment: did you ever find the root of this issue? I can confirm it's nothing to do with libraries